# How many subclasses can be declared for a sealed class?

Tags: java, java-17

What is the maximum number of sub classes that can be listed for a sealed class (analogous for interfaces):

```java
public sealed class Foo permits A, B, C {
   // How many sub classes can  ^^^^^^^
   // be listed here?
}
```

Does the *language* actually define a limit; i.e., is it virtually infinite at the level of the language?

If there is no such limit at the level of the language, it seems that an *implementation* still must have a technical limit. Somewhere there ought to be a list that stores some kind of representation of the sub classes permitted. I would expect a 16 or 32 bit integer to be used then.

Comment: 64K? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.31

Comment: @akarnokd I agree, 64k seems to be the technical limit. Thanks for the pointer to the doc.

Comment: @akarnokd Don't forget every `Constant_Class_info` also requires an associated `Constant_Utf8_info`, so really 32K.  But really, less.

Answer (score 19):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72775712/3553087) is correct, but I'll add that even in JVMS 4.7.31 (the `PermittedSubtypes` attribute), you won't find a specific limit.  But since every permitted subtype must correspond to a `Constant_Class_info` in the constant pool, and the constant pool is limited to 64K entries, and each `Class` constant has an associate `String` constant, so you could not get more than 32K in any case.  Of course, you probably have other things in your class too, which compete for the constant pool, so you won't get that either.  But the answer is, effectively "thousands".

Comment: The referenced answer points more or less to the `u2 number_of_classes` part of the PermittedSubclasses_attribute. u2. But yeah, you will exceed the constant pool capacity first, for any intent and purposes, as your construction shows.

Comment: At the minimum, you need a `Constant_Class_info` for the class itself and its superclass (and an entry for each’s name). Then, an entry for the `PermittedSubclasses` attribute name itself. So, we have `(65534 - 5) / 2` possible class info entries and indeed, I could generate an interface with 32764 permitted classes (and not one more).

Comment: @Holger You can set the super class to 0, if your class is `java.lang.Object`. It probably is not `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: That would only gain you space for another class reference if your class does not declare any members, which would clearly violate JLS §4.3.2, and without a constructor, it wouldn’t work well with any subclass, not to speak of the requirement that all permitted subclasses must be within the same module (i.e. `java.base`) and no anonymous subclasses can exist. So a class file for a sealed `java.lang.Object` may get accepted by a stand-alone parser, but won’t work on source level nor in actual runtime environments. In contrast, the interface I generated could be actually loaded into the runtime.

Answer (score 12):

The JLS (Java Language Spec) generally includes no limits at all. Even though there are lots of limits. It's the JVMS (Java Virtual Machine Specification) that includes limits. This makes sense: A lot of these limits are fundamentally related to bytecode and class file format concepts, which are ideas that the JLS doesn't know about - in other words, even if the JLS wanted to, it couldn't possibly describe the limits in terms that are defined in the JLS.

For example, the max size of a method is 'measured' in bytecode instructions, which isn't a java-the-language concept in the first place.

Hence, the JVMS is where to look for such limits. For example [JVM Spec §4.7.31](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.31) (as provided by @akarnokd, good find!).

There are limits on:

- Number of methods in a type
- Number of fields in a type
- Number of interfaces in your `implements` list
- Number of parameters a method can have
- Size of a method's "frame" (how much stack space it needs)
- Size of the number of local slots. These last 2 bullets more or less translate in java-the-language to a limit on number of local vars you can have.
- Number of bytecode per method. Easiest way to run into this limit is by having a large `finally` block attached to a try with loads of `catch` blocks. The finally block is replicated for all of them. Nest try blocks for exponential bytecode growth!
- Number of type params you can have in signatures.
- Number of entries in the constant pool. This would appear in java-the-language as limits on the number of literals you can include in a single class.

I'm sure I'm forgetting a few.

There are further limits that are in no spec; such as memory and heap size limits, and a lot of details about command line switches (for example, on a bunch of JVM releases and OSes, any `-Xss` parameter (that sets stack sizes) that isn't evenly divisible by a 'word boundary', whose definition depends on OS and architecture, was completely ignored) - all unspecced.

Some of that makes sense (the exact specifics on precisely how much heap you really can reserve depends on too many factors to attempt to document in detail), some of it really doesn't (the fact that the tool switches act like they are highly specced, having 2 layers of 'less specced' in both `-X` and `-XX` doesn't really mesh well with the idea that neither the JVMS nor the JLS mentions the tools available or their command line switches in much detail.

Comment: Found another exotic one: Depth of array dims. I don't think you can make a `String[][][]` with 256 or more `[]`.

Comment: The array depth has [a specified limit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1): “*An array type descriptor is valid only if it represents 255 or fewer dimensions.*”